# Asp.net MVC and AngularJS Boilerplate framework

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core-mvc, enterprise, aspnetboilerplate

We are looking to upgrade our current product. The current product is built using web forms (asp.net), c# and Sql server. The current product does not follow much of the best practices such as IOC, Unit of work, Repository pattern etc, however it does follow three layered architecture.

We would like to build the new product from scratch using best practices so that product can be scaled up when required. Our product needs to be a multi tennant web application which should be mobile friendly if viewed on a mobile device. We have found aspnet zero boiler plate which follows best practices but it seems a wee bit limited for us. The disappointment for us is the effort it requires to just add one new field as we would need to add it into multiple places and then recompile the product and publish it. Our product also rely on multiple forms and each form can contain hundereds of fields and on top of that each of our customers may not use all fields in the same form so we need a mechanism to hide and display fields based on customer's credentials. The dynamic creation of forms is a must requirement for us. I have listed below the requirements that we need:

1. Must follow Industry standard best practices (IOC, Unit of work, Repository, logging etc)
2. Ability to create forms dynamically and to report on these fields.
3. Should not rely on compiling and publishing the product for adding additonal field.
4. Custom business rules for each customer
5. Adhoc web based reporting
6. Full auditing to record changed and new value for certain or all fields.
7. Fully scalable
8. Role/User based permissions

Is there a suitable framework for achieving above or do we need to build it ourselves?

Answer (score 2):

You used the tag "aspnetboilerplate" So why don't use them ?
I have been learning it since 2016 and it really helpful. A lot of things is well documented and its open source and free. Give it a try.

Comment: See my answer to Alper Ebicoglu, below.

Comment: Do you have a software that do that in Web Forms? I ask because that can give us a hint.

Comment: We currently have a table which contains list of all possible fields for a given form and this form is then linked to customer form table to show only those fields which are required by customer. We then dynamically create controls based on this information. For adding new fields without compiling, there are some CMS which do that but we are looking for asp.net mvc/angular approach.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I was thinking about a CMS as you say. Will investigate if there is a CMS that is made with that approach.

Comment: please do share, if you find anything.

Comment: were you able to find anything? Thanks

Comment: Sorry but nothing like ABP.

Answer (score -1):

All the features you specified are included in AspNet Zero application framework. You can start a free demo to see the user interface. Check out the documentation. If you like it you can buy. There's 30 day money guarantee back.

https://aspnetzero.com/

Comment: I have done that and I see following two short commings: you need to do a lot of manual work to add a new field and then compile and publish the product, the second issue is the creation of dynamic forms, currently with the framework you need to manually create forms for adding/viewing/editing a form. Do you know the work around for above short commings?

Comment: i think you need a rad tool (rapid application development tool). With the help of rad tools you can easily create forms, new screens but on the other hand they'll limit you in some situations. When you have a long term project i will not suggest a rad tool. You can see Telerik Asp.net Core

Comment: We use telerik controls. Telerik Asp.net core is a set of controls and it does not provide any functionality for dynamic creations of forms.